# Minimally sized kiddush cup for sale

Tags: product-recommendation, shiurim-measurements, kiddush-cup

I read that a reviit (the minimal size for a cup used for kiddush, havdala etc) is 86.4 mL according to the generally accepted view (see [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA,_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94#.D7.9E.D7.99.D7.93.D7.95.D7.AA_.D7.A0.D7.A4.D7.97) for options). Does anyone know where I can get a cup that is exactly that size or as close to it as possible? I don't need to be using extra wine when I make kiddush every week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this one](http://www.didriks.com/Pure-Shot-Glass.html). It's 94 mL which is as close as I'd feel comfortable with. The manufacturer's website is [here](http://www.zwieselkristallglas-shop.com/shop/article/articlelist!carousel.action?category=000019&productline=000026&article=112843&brand=schott#/112843), but the first link has free shipping in the USA.

Lechayim!

Comment: are you talking to yourself??

Comment: @avi You caught me! See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/306/if-i-know-the-answer-to-a-question

Comment: Answering your own question is different from talking to yourself :)  "try this one." is something you say to other people  :)P

Comment: Hhmm. Are you sure that's an accurate size? I've encountered many of these types of cups that are larger than they advertise. Also, I wonder if Ramma would call it a gluk glass being that the mouth is small.

Comment: @user6591 I have measured it with a TD volumetric pipette. It may even be a bit bigger than advertised. As for narrow, it's transparent so you can still see the wine, so that shouldn't be a problem. Plus narrow allows for less volume loss at the top, if you're ensuring you don't spill.

Comment: Yeah. They're usually bigger. Sometimes by a lot.  Is it your chiddush that clear helps,  or you saw that somewhere?

Comment: @user6591 Honestly, I don't remember. In any event, [nearly?] all Acharonim are Meikil if there's some Tzorekh, so we're not talking about a major concern.

Comment: True. And since everyone has their own cup it may be less of a concern too.

Comment: They're also good quality. Mine lasted me from Nov '11 till an hour ago. יהי זכרו ברוך

Answer (score 4):

[This cup is 3 oz which is 88.7 ml](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001A6DP6Y) and is actually a kiddush cup :)

Comment: To be clear, your cup is 3 ounces. I don't know enough laws about advertising but I bet they can be slightly off and still label it that way. My answer above is a European manufacturer who labeled it as 94 mL. But, yes, yours is an actual kiddush cup!

Comment: Compare with this cup: http://www.amazon.com/Woodbury-Pewter-Communion-Cup-oz/dp/B001A6LR82/ref=sr_1_11?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1323197647&sr=1-11 They are clearly the same cup but one is $10 cheaper! I wonder if it counts as AZ..

Comment: I guess the Jewish star makes demand lower so they have to charge more :)

Comment: avi, that's the opposite of how supply and demand are supposed to work. More likely, it's for the extra work and additional supply chain steps required to put the star on.

Comment: @IsaacMoses That is actually how supply and demand work in Judaica, however.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Whenever you have a niche population which has a higher demand for an item than the general population, the item catering to the niche population will cost more than the identical item geared towards the general population.

Comment: @avi Exactly; higher demand.

Comment: @DoubleAA Interestingly there is an extremely important (IMHO) responsum of R. Qafih (dealing with temporal quantities) where he says that small differences to not make a difference.

Comment: @mevaqesh The [Mishna](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Menachot.12.4) implies the margin of error is at most 0.065%

Comment: @DoubleAA That Mishna actually implies no such thing. All it implies is that when the law has a specific measurement, then that measurement is a fixed border and can't be passed.  But there is no law for the number of ml or oz.

Comment: @avi The Mishna didn't use ml or oz because those weren't invented yet, but as you say the border is fixed and approximations aren't good enough, which is what I said.