# How much of a minimal sized kiddush cup must be consumed?

Tags: blessing, shiurim-measurements, grapes-wine, kiddush-cup

If someone uses a kiddush cup that is exactly (or close to) the bare minimum ([see this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12041/minimally-sized-kiddush-cup-for-sale)) needed to fulfill the obligation, how much of that cup must he drink?

Do the different times one must drink a cup of wine have different requirements? If so, what are those requirements? Some of the times I can think of (add more if you can think of them):

- Kiddush Friday (or Yom Tov) Night
- Kiddush Shabbat (or Yom Tov) Day
- Havdalah
- When Bentching with Wine
- Under the Chupah at a Wedding
- At a circumcision.
- Bride and Groom at Sheva Brachot
- Chol HaMoed
- 4 cups of wine at Seder, Pesach night
- when drinking a cup of wine for no reason

Or is the obligation the same no matter when you're blessing and drinking a cup of wine?

Comment: Chol HaMoed? Do you mean kiddush on shabbat chol hamoed or for the mitzva of simcha be'yayin during chol hamoed?

Comment: @DoubleAA: simcha be'yayin durin chol hamoed. I assume there would be no difference between a regular shabbat and shabbat chol hamoed.

Answer (score 5):

See [here](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/halak64/27kiddush3.doc).

In summary, the answers vary from tasting (a small sip), a cheekful (varies per person and is usually assumed to be the majority of the reviit), a reviit (86.4 mL).

- Kiddush Friday (or Yom Tov) Night -- ideally a cheekful, ex post facto even a reviit.
- Kiddush Shabbat (or Yom Tov) Day -- ideally a cheekful, ex post facto even a reviit.
- Havdalah -- ideally a reviit, ex post facto a cheekful.
- When Bentching with Wine -- ideally a reviit ([Shulchan Aruch 190:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&pgnum=173)), ex post facto a cheekful.
- Under the Chupah at a Wedding -- tasting.
- At a circumcision -- tasting.
- Bride and Groom at Sheva Brachot -- tasting.
- Chol HaMoed -- for simchat yom tov -- a reviit.
- 4 cups of wine at Seder, Pesach night -- ideally the full cup, next ideal is majority of the cup, ex post facto a cheekful.
- when drinking a cup of wine for no reason  -- either tasting or a reviit, ex post facto a cheekful.

When I say 'ex post facto' I mean that by doing so you have fulfilled the relevant obligation but may be stuck with other (usually bracha achrona) problems.

Comment: Re "ideally a cheekful, ex post facto even a reviit": I didn't check your source document, but for most people (and IIRC according to some authorities for everyone) a cheekful is less than a _r'viis_.

Comment: @msh210 It's not a typo. A cheekful is indeed assumed to be less than a reviit and for kiddush a reviit is the bedieved option.

Comment: with regards to a Birchat Hamazon, please see Mishna Berura 309:14, who quotes the opinion that ex post facto a cheekful is enough (the Taz), but then mentions that all the Acharonim dismiss this: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&pgnum=174

Comment: where is your source for "Bride and Groom at Sheva Brachot -- ideally a reviit, ex post facto a cheekful." the document you're quoting from mentions that the one leading the grace after meals must do so. It doesn't mention anything about the bride and bridegroom. Wouldn't that be just a taste?

Comment: @Menachem Et Chata'ay Ani Mazkir HaYom! Good catch -- that was my bad. Also, I think you meant 190:14 not 309. I don't see why you point me there though; he ends up agreeing with me.

Comment: I understood the Mishna Berura (I did mean 109) to say that the Taz is the one who brings that "ideally one should drink a reviit, but ex post facto a cheekful is enough" but everyone disagrees with this. But reading it again, it may be that they agree, but are just disagreeing whether one can say an after blessing.

Comment: @Menachem I agree with your second read: they are just discussing after-blessings.