# Do we need to make Birkas Mein Shalosh after havdalah?

Tags: halacha, blessing, grapes-wine, havdalah, birkat-meeyn-shalosh

I [know](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-issues-measurements.htm) that the minimum amount of wine to be drunk for havdalah is only a cheekful (m’lo lugmav). But realistically, often the person reciting havdalah will drink the whole--or almost the whole--cup of wine, which is usually larger than the [strict definition of a revi'it](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Reference_of_Measurements_in_Halacha#Revi.27it) as 3-3.3 ounces.*   So, is a birkas mein shalosh required afterward?

*(See also [here](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/pouring-winegrape-juice-back-into-the-container) for a comment stating that one must actually drink a full r'viis in order to avoid the shaylo in question.)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12058/how-much-of-a-minimal-sized-kiddush-cup-must-be-consumed

Comment: Yes, and everybody I ever saw does it :)

Comment: Why would you think not?

Comment: Sometimes people forget; most people I've observed making havdalah who are careful to keep halacha will say it.

Comment: I assume that the minimum requirement for Havdalah is the same as for the 4 cups during Seder. A bracha achrona is made after the 4th cup, there, so I assume same thing here.

Comment: @Sam Only because I never see people do it!

Comment: @Sam Also, there is a big gray area regarding how much is drunk. If you're using a kiddush cup that's ~3 ounces (the "small" revi'it) and/or you don't drink it all because you pour some on the candle, and/or you drink only one cheekful because that's all that's technically required (according to Star-K link above)...then there is a question.

Comment: @danf that's not a great assumption fyi

Comment: @sam Also I would think not because we don't make it after kiddush usually. although then you usually have bentching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one is chayiv to make an al hagafen since there is no special exclusion on the chiyuv of making an al hagafen for havdala. (In fact, not a proof but, the Aruch Hashulchan actually maintains that we don't generally make a bracha on besamim but do for havdala.)

Comment: Probably if people are lax it is because they're not used to making an al hagafen (at least alone) since most times we dink wine nowadays it's together with a meal.

Comment: Curious: Why would we not generally make a brocha on b'samim?

Comment: @SAH I believe the Aruch Hashulchan maintains that we don't have hanaah from smells like they once did and that in the case of birchos hareiach that actually effects the bracha status.

Comment: @loewian Really? I believe you that the S"A says that. But I was taught that we still say (at least) atzei, eisvei, and minei b'somim.

Comment: I don't think the comon minhag is like the Aruch Hashulchan on this.

Comment: @loewian Or else we follow Aruch Hashulchan insofar as we don't say Hareiach these days

Comment: @loewian it would be great if you could bring a source for the first sentence of your answer. Thanks