# Obligation of Tzitzit with multiple 4 cornered garments

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, tzitzis, tallit-gadol, tallit-katan

According to Halacha, if one is wearing multiple four cornered garments, is it that each one of them individually is obligated in Tzitzit with a beracha, or is it only one which needs Tzitzit which can make the other ones B’dieved?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.8.12?lang=bi

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/115028/6592

Comment: Safek berakhot l'hakel. Many avoid any issue bc they always have on the t. Katan even at night it's a protection per the Arizal though not obligated, and Sefardim don't bless on the t. Katan, only the gadol. If you put on a poncho afterward why would you say a brocho -- you are already performing the miswa continually by having at least one set on and that's a continual and huge miswa every momen, right?

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to learn this out from Shabbat candles a la Sefardim. Is tzitzith an obligation of the garment or on the man who is wearing a beged?
Well in nerot Shabbat as well as Chanukkah it's an obligation of the house; if someone else lights with a brocho it's l'batela a waste because there's already Light that's lit, per Sefardim. Why wouldn't it be the same here? Is it an obligation of the garment or of the wearer? Therefore if he's already wearing one and made a brocho -- and he should have in mind if he's putting on another set later and intend that in the brocho -- then he's good until next day.

Check how you phrased your question. How can a thing be obligated, right?