# Bentching with wine on the table

Tags: bentching, grapes-wine

If one is not benching on a Kos is it forbidden to do so if a bottle of wine is not removed from the table?

Comment: Is there a reason you believe this would be forbidden?

Comment: I recall learning that one should remove the wine from the table - but I cannot find it anywhere. Phantom Halacha?

Comment: Isn't the better solution to just use the wine for Bentching?? Why do we have to hide from Mitzvot???

Comment: @DoubleAA - maybe you want it for the next Kiddush or Havadala, or maybe you aren't up to drinking more alcohol? (Ignoring kabbalistic reasons not to use a Kos w/o a mezuman)

Comment: @danny ok so I'm right in only 98% of cases. mea culpa.

Comment: @DoubleAA - and when bentching w/o a Mezuman, according to the Arizal - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86291/501

Comment: @DannySchoemann you had said ignoring kabbalistic reasons. and anyway accd to that there's no need to remove the wine since it couldn't be used anyway. you're just limiting the relevant cases, but it's still 98% of them